# Output list of next 6 months in Twig

Tags: loops, date, twig

I'm trying to output a dropdown menu of the next 6 months but having no luck. I know I'm doing something stupid here. Can anyone help out? Here's where I'm at:

```
<select>
  <option value="">This month</option>
    {% for i in range(1, 6) %}
      <option value="">
        {{ now.date|date_modify("+" ~ i ~ " month")|date('F Y') }}
      </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: The language is missing. And _"having no luck"_ is not a problem description; write a proper one.

Comment: its `"now"` instead of `now.date`

Comment: Thanks DarkBee but doesn't help. Currently outputs as:
March 2018
March 2018
May 2018
May 2018
July 2018
July 2018...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a helpful comment on PHP's `strtotime` documentation page:

> WARNING when using "next month", "last month", "+1 month",  "-1 month"
>   or any combination of +/-X months. It will give non-intuitive results
>   on Jan 30th and 31st.
>
> ...
>
> (Source: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#107331)

So you should use `first day of +i month` instead of `+i month`:

```
<select>
  <option value="">This month</option>
    {% for i in 1..6 %}
      <option value="">
        {{ "now"|date_modify("first day of +" ~ i ~ " month")|date('F Y') }}
      </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Notice that I changed `now.date` to `"now"`, as pointed out by @DarkBee. I also used `for i in 1..6` instead of the `range` function; the `1..6` is just syntactic sugar as described in the [documentation of the `range` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/range.html).

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much.